# It looks like we don't support this file format - aws s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, nestjs, multer

I created in nest.js a fileuploader (pdfs files, docs, images) using s3, the problem is that sometimes it's working and sometimes doesn't...
When I to get a photo or to download and open it, this is what I get:
[image]

this is my code:
**service file:**

```
async upload(fileName: string, file: Buffer) {
    await this.s3Client.send(
      new PutObjectCommand({
        Bucket: '######',
        Key: fileName,
        Body: file,
        ContentEncoding: 'base64'
      }),
    );
  }

  async uploadAndGetFileUrl(fileName: string, file: Buffer): Promise<string> {
    const uuid = uuidv4();
    // const uniqueFileName = `${uuid}-${fileName}`;
    // await this.upload(uniqueFileName, file);
    const fileExtension = fileName.split('.').pop(); // Get the file extension
    const uniqueFileName = `${uuid}.${fileExtension}`;
    await this.upload(uniqueFileName, file);
  
    // Return the file URL after uploading
    return `https://polosteelart-files.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/${uniqueFileName}`;
  }
```

Comment: so if i use my local backend is it working fine, but if i use the one hosted with aws, is uploading the files, but have the error i showed in my post